# If command not executing despite the test being true

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I'm currently making a program to use pre-set information stored in .txt files to alter what the program executes. I am, however, having a problem with the following code segment not functioning properly.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:load

cls
if exist settings (
    cd settings
    set /p welcomemessage=<"launch message".txt
    set /p color=<color.txt
    cd..
    color !color!
    if !welcomemessage!==false (
        goto command
    )
)

...

:command

...
```

The second if (if !welcomemessage!==false...) is not functioning properly, as it does not skip to command as it should. I have found a way to make it work by moving it outside the main if block and replacing ! with %, but I'd like to know what's going wrong.

The color function functions properly, and if I echo the value of welcomemessage, even inside the first if block, it reads "false", though the second if still does not activate.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the contents of your file. We'll be needing the code that is interpreting it if you want help.

Comment: @ChrisCooney This is Windows shell.

Comment: This is the segment of code that is giving me trouble; the two files it is interpreting are just .txt files with the standard color set format (e.g. "47") in one and "true" or "false" in the other. Each of which is inside the settings folder, which is in the same directory as the .bat file this code segment is running from.

Comment: @Endoro Yes; I can put an    echo !welcomemessage!    inside the if block after    set /p welcomemessage=<"launch message".txt    and it will echo "false", though the second if doesn't seem to be able to read it

Comment: Depending on the exact contents of the text file, !welcomemessage! may have a space on one side or the other, or quotes, etc.  Try an `echo -!welcomemessage!-` -- note the `-` on each side--you're trying to see if there's a space or some other character in there.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the reported behaviour by inserting a leading space into the file "Launch message.txt"

What is happening is that within the `FOR` loop, the comparison is made against the current value of the variable. " false" is NOT the same as "false" so the TRUE branch of the `if` is not triggered.

Outside of the for loop, the statement

```
if %welcomemessage%==false ECHO its false
```

is interpreted as

```
if  false==false ECHO its false
```

since the parse-time value of the variable is substituted in before the statement is executed. Note there are TWO spaces after the `if`. Executing this will result in TRUE.

By way of proof, try this (outside of the loop)

if %welcomemessage%==false ECHO its false
 if %welcomemessage%==!welcomemessage! ECHO false it is
 if "%welcomemessage%"=="!welcomemessage!" ECHO really, it is

Note that the 'false it is' message is missing...

Answer (score 0):

If there is a space there then some debugging like the line below will help you spot it.  I added this answer to illustrate a simpler way to handle the files too.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:load

cls
if exist settings (
    set /p welcomemessage=<"settings\launch message.txt"
    set /p color=<"settings\color.txt"
    echo "!welcomemessage!" "!color!" & pause
    color !color!
    if /i "!welcomemessage!"=="false" goto command
)

...

:command

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that what I had not tried was doing the following line of code: `echo "!welcomemessage!"` which I found displayed `"false "` which is not the same as `"false"`. (NOTE: var will be used as any variable, not literally the text string "var" and not necessarily the same for every occurrence) This tells us that the `echo var >> var.txt` and the `echo var > var.txt` (which I used to generate and edit the "launch message.txt" and "color.txt" files in a different section of the program) both add a space to the end of what they insert into var.txt (this space is in the form of an additional line below the text inside the .txt file).

To correct this I used the following code: (I also shortened the variable name)

```
set /p message=<"launch message".txt
set message=!message: =!
set /p color=<color.txt
set color=!color: =!
```

The `set var=!var: =!` replaces spaces (on the left of the = sign with nothing (on the right)

After these operations were completed the if block worked properly.